# Regular expression to allow numbers between -90.0 and +90.0

Tags: c#, regex

What is the regular expression to allow for numbers between -90.0 and +90.0?  The numbers in between can be floating or whole numbers.

Comment: Why a regular expression? Why not just use numerical comparison?

Comment: Including or excluding 90?  Do you need to support "e" notation?  If so, that's going to be one ugly regex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a Regex for this. Use [`Double.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) (or [`Double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)) if your data is stored in a string, and then check the resulting value to ensure that it falls within the desired range. For example:

```
public bool IsInRange(string value)
{
   bool isInRange = false;

   double parsed = 0;
   if (Double.TryParse(value, out parsed))
   {
      // use >= and <= if you want the range to be from -90.0 to 90.0 inclusive
      isInRange = value > -90.0 && value < 90.0;
   }

   return isInRange;
}
```

If your value is already a `double`, then it's even easier -- no parsing required.

Answer (score 9):

Not that you really want to use a Regex here (you should parse it, instead, and do the comparison on a numeric type - such as float, or double).  But, you could do this:

```
-?(\d|([1-8][0-9])(\.\d)?)|(90(\.0)?)
```

This will match -90.0 to 90.0, inclusive.  If you want it to be exclusive, drop the 90.0 clause.

- negative (optional):

  `-?`
- single digit

  OR double digit, 10-89

  `\d|([1-8][0-9])`

  PLUS decimal, 0-9 (optional):

  `(\.\d)?`
- OR 90

  `90`

  PLUS decimal, 0 (optional):

  `(\.0)?`

If you want to support more decimal points, then change the 0-89.9 clause to:

- Specific precision (seven, in this case) `\d|([1-8][0-9])(\.\d{1,7})?`
- Infinite precision `\d|([1-8][0-9])(\.\d+)?`

Escape, if necessary

Comment: Could add as an option... `([-+]?([0-8]\.\d{1,7}|9\.0{1,7})[eE][+]?0{0,2}1)` or is that going too far?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: No regex goes too far!  I won't stop until the entire world is composed solely of regex ;)

Answer (score 1):

["Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

This is a problem that would be better solved with a check.  But, if you want a regex, you can have a regex.

```
-?0*((90(\.0*)?)|([1-8]?\d(\.\d*)?))
```

will work, I think.  Match an optional '-', followed by any number of zeros, followed by either 90 with any number of zeros, or a number that consists of an optional tens digit between 1 and 8, followed by a ones digit, followed by a optional decimal and decimal places.  But you see why using a regex for this is so messy.  Check the bounds as a numbers, not a series of numerals.

Comment: That regex matches numbers in the range the OP specified, but it also matches `0123456789`, `9876543210`, `9099999999`, `-00000000000000000`, and many other invalid strings.

Comment: Fixed it, I think.  Now the numbers following the decimal place can only show up when the decimal place is there.

Comment: It still matches `900000000000000`

Comment: Oops, I missed that.  You can see that I don't use regexes very often.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward regex for +/- option sign of a 90.0 range with optional float of 1 decimal place would be :

`[-+]?90(?:\.0?)?|[-+]?(?:\d|[1-8]\d)(?:\.\d?)?`

Expanded

```
   #   [-+]  90.0

   [-+]? 90
   (?: \. 0? )?
|  
   #    [-+]  89.9  to   0.0
   #           0.0  to  89.9

   [-+]? 
   (?:
        \d 
     |  [1-8] \d 
   )
   (?: \. \d? )?
```

Comment: You are matching `90.9`

Comment: @Toto - Indeed, I factored the original wrong `-90\.0|-(?:\d|[1-8]\d)\.\d|(?:\d|[1-8]\d)\.\d|90\.0`