# Regex to match even hex numbers in Tcl?

Tags: regex, tcl

Is there away to write a Tcl regex to verify that a string is a hex number that is even?

Comment: A hex number is easy. Checking eveness is still possible (actually, still easy) because the last digit determines that - but in general, you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098086/to-use-or-not-to-use-regular-expressions/4098123#4098123 and heed its wisdom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tcl code will do the work:

```
if {[regexp -linestop -nocase {^[\da-f]*[02468ace]$} $input]} {
    # Success
} else {
    # Fail
}
```

Note that a, c and e are also even numbers and that you need -nocase to match a-f as well as A-F.

Comment: I added braces around the if condition to delay evaluation

Comment: You probably don't need `-linestop`; the default “match the whole string” behavior is suitable for this sort of task.

Answer (score 4):

Does it need to be a regex?

```
proc is_even {n} {expr {($n & 1) == 0}}

if {[is_even 0xdeadbeef]} {puts even} else {puts odd}
```