# Perl regular expression: how to replace all desired character except of the first one

Tags: perl

I have a regular expression that replaces all special characters with % (for database searching with LIKE). It looks like this:

```
$string =~ s/[^ a-zA-Z0-9]/%/g;
```

However I don't know how to change that expression to replace all desired special characters EXCEPT for the first one in a string. So if my string look like

```
"&Hi I'm smart(yeah right...)"
```

it would be

```
"&Hi I%m smart%yeah right%%%%"
```

(Right now the first '&' is also replaced).

Can any one help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changes all but the first instance of the match target into a percent symbol:

```
{
    my $count = 0;
    $string =~ s{([^ a-zA-Z0-9])}{$count++ ? "%" : $1}ge;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) requiring at least one character:

```
s/(?<=.)[^ a-zA-Z0-9]/%/g;
```

Comment: That only works if the first character is a special character. It does not work to change all but the first such special character in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

```
substr($string, 1) =~ s/[^ a-zA-Z0-9]/%/g;
```

**Update**: The above only works if the special character is the first character of the string. The following works no matter where it's located:

```
my $re = qr/[^ a-zA-Z0-9]/;
my @parts = split(/($re)/, $string, 2);
$parts[2] =~ s/$re/%/g if @parts == 3;
$string = join('', @parts);
```

Comment: But what if the first “special character” is not the first character?

Comment: @tchrist, then that would be a different question with a different answer.

Comment: @tchrist, or maybe not. After re-reading a few more times, I'm with you.

Comment: I think you could possibly do it with [a nested regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678422/regex-matching-irreducible-fraction/5695425#5695425), but I think the `s///e` solution that counts is cleaner to look at than any nested thing could be.

Comment: /e is definitely cleaner, @tchrist. Both of my solution fall into the "here's something you hadn't thought of you might one day find useful". Besides, you already gave the /e solution.